# How to change the window theme in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, themes, metacity

I use Gnome Shell on Ubuntu 11.10. I can use Gnome Tweak Tool to change the GTK theme and icon theme, but I can't change my window theme. If I select anything other than the default theme "Adwaita", and restart gnome shell, it reverts to the accessibility theme. How can I change the window/Metacity

Comment: Whatever theme you download has to have a metacity theme too...

Comment: .. and it has to be a GTk 3 theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download a theme>extract it>Inside it should have something similar to this:

[image]

As you can see there's a gtk-3.0 and a metacity-1 folder. These two folders should be in: /home/user/.themes/.

Then open up Gnome Tweak Tool>go to Theme>Window theme>Scroll down to the theme you want.
[image]

Log out, and done.

Comment: hmm...weird. The Ambience Blue theme worked for me, but the old Ambiance theme doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: The orange Ubuntu Ambience Theme is a Compiz Theme, Gnome Shell uses Mutter for compositing that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
gconf-editor
```

and change the theme in /desktop/gnome/shell/windows

[image]