# How do you change the highligter for files?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, filemanager

How do you change the highligter for files?
Don't know how you do this. I do know how it happened. How do I change it back to orange? SEE IMAGE AND ASK ME QUESTIONS. Also I am using 11.10.[image: s]

Comment: You are suppose to ASK the questions not us, detailing what you did etc... , Change the theme.

Comment: Question in title. Sorry I'll copy it down. Also it doesn't work in 11.10. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, I see you're using Gnome Shell, what theme are you trying to use?.

Comment: I am trying to Zukitwo. @Uri you were right. I was only changing to themes that still didn't have a theme for that and so it resorted to the default which changed when I upgraded to some ugly thing show above. Thank you.

Comment: Please see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62495/how-to-change-the-window-theme-in-gnome-shell/62500#62500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a change in the theme or the color scheme. You must either edit it, or use a different one.

Comment: Can't edit so changing this question. To how to do that thanks.