# How to change the color themes in gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, colors

How to change the color themes in gnome 3? Anyone? (Note using 11.10)

Comment: Hi, I may not understand question properly. However if you are looking for theme tab -- then install gnome-tweak-tool and try it.

Comment: You have to edit the theme itself, look at /home/user/.themes/ if you have installed any GTK3 themes FOR the Gnome Shell themes look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/62495/how-to-change-the-window-theme-in-gnome-shell/62500#62500

Comment: Also since I have the Kubuntu-desktop installed, I just went to K-desktop settings and changed the color theme there while I had gnome3 running

Comment: Is the GNOME 3 project so new, that they cannot safely include a few themes in their settings panel without the need for installing additional software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to directly edit the theme. The themes are located under /usr/share/themes. For the Adwaita theme, the colors are declared in the gtk.css file.

Comment: So the gnome theme is written in traditional css? or is it an altered version?

Comment: Is there a way to preview the changes?

Comment: @Calmarius No, you just have to edit and then try it out.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-colors gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then, run the command in the terminal:

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then go to `theme/icon theme`.

Answer (score 2):

The new way:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-colors gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then, run the command in the terminal:

```
gnome-tweaks
```

Then go to theme/icon theme.

Comment: Wow, I did this an the Yaru-Dark theme is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Some pretty nice ones can be found here (in German):

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Gnome_Shell/Themes#Shell-Designs