# Colors in my Google Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, google

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I've started to realize that my browser colours have kind of changed, for an example, when text is highlighted in search bars or what not, they are highlighted orange instead of blue, does anyone know how I could change it?
For more understanding I will attach image. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Ubuntu. If you use the default theme, Yaru, then the accent color is orange. It appears that this selection color in Google Chrome now adheres to the default color theme of the desktop. As such, that is a good thing because it increases visual consistency across applications.

To change that, you must [change your GTK theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62495/how-to-change-the-window-theme-in-gnome-shell). That change will affect all applications.